# unshare -r: Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted

Tags: bash, profile, unshare

When I run `unshare -r`, I get

```
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted
```

The id still shows I'm root,

```
❯ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root),65534(nogroup)
```

What does this error/warning mean? What generates it? Can it be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely a result of something that happens during the login shell, observe

```
# explicitly launch login shell
$> unshare -r /bin/bash -l
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted
```

vs

```
# run a regular shell
$> unshare -r /bin/bash
```

In my case I had a `~/.profile` which was running,

```
systemctl -q is-active graphical.target
```

And I can prove this with

```
$> unshare -r -- systemctl -q is-active graphical.target
Failed to connect to bus: Operation not permitted
```

### Shell Startup Sequence

Note `~/.profile` isn't the only file your shell reads when you login. To find out more read your shells docs.

Answer (score -2):

This message is probably generated by some command in your shell’s start-up files; judging by the message’s contents, it’s probably something related to D-Bus.

To find out which command in particular it is, you can use either of those two commands:

```
$ unshare -r /bin/bash -ix </dev/null 2>&1 | less
$ unshare -r /bin/bash -lix </dev/null 2>&1 | less
```

These will display all the commands that are executed during shell startup; the former will debug normal interactive shell startup, the latter will debug login shells. Use `/` to search for the error message; a line before it should contain the command which generated it.